# JSON layer does not show when .setview changes

Tags: geojson, mapbox, json, d3

I've set a Mapbox map with a GeoJSON layer overlaying it. The problem is that with the default set values, the JSON layer shows up just fine. However, If I change the `.setView` too much, the JSON layer doesn't show up, just the map. Can anyone explain to me why this is occurring?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
   <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
   <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script> 
   <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.8/mapbox.js'></script>  
   <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.8/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
   <style>
      html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .key path {
        display: none;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
   <script>
      queue()
          .defer(d3.json, 'med.json') 
          .await(makeMap)

      function makeMap(error, data) {
        var color = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([10, 400])
              .range(['#F0F0D0', '#930F16']);


          L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWluaDUiLCJhIjoiaXlwYTAxOCJ9.Ny8tujUV7-0dbVHVu3RQ_w';
          var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'minh5.d0e19262')
              //ERROR OCCURS HERE
              .setView([41.9, -91.5], 4); // try changing the coordinates to 41.9, -431

          L.tileLayer('mapbox.streets', {
              maxZoom: 18,
              minZoom: 1,
              attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://www.mapbox.com/m">Mapbox</a> Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0">CC BY SA</a>.'
          }).addTo(map);
          function style(feature) {
            return {
                fillColor: color(feature.properties.count),
                weight: 1,
                opacity: 0.2,
                color: 'black',
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            };
          }

      function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
          weight: 10,
          color: '#666',
          dashArray: '',
          fillOpacity: 0.5
        });
        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
          layer.bringToFront();
        }
        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
      }

      var geojson;

      function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
      }

      function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
      }

      function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
          mouseover: highlightFeature,
          mouseout: resetHighlight,
          click: zoomToFeature
        });
      }


      geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
      }).addTo(map);


        var info = L.control();
        info.onAdd = function (map) {
          this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
          this.update();
          return this._div;
        };
        info.update = function (feature) {
          this._div.innerHTML = (feature ?
            '<b>'  + 'Block ID:' + feature.id + '<br>' + feature.count + ' Republican Primary Voters</b><br />'
            : '');
        };
        info.addTo(map);


      };

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what coords are you trying to change to? right now it says `// try changing the coordinates to 41.9, -431`

Comment: Sidenote: why are you including both mapbox.js and leaflet.js?You only need mapbox.js in this example.Including Leaflet.js(alongside leaflet.css) is redundant and an unnecessary load.